# High CPU interupts when CPU usage is very low

Tags: cpu-usage

I have a CentOS 6 VM running on Win2012 Hyper-v server. This server has 12 processers, 60GB memory, Raid-5 SSD. There's nothing running on the server yet, but it has very high cpu interrupts, always 12K. Is this normal?

====Update===

It looks that one cpu give 1K interrupts.

I changed the cpu to 2, then it shows about 2000 interrupts

then I changed the cpu to 8, it shows about 8000 interrupts

It seems that this is normal.

```
# vmstat 1 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 59175084  39128 461120    0    0    24    10 1010   17  1  3 96  0  0
 0  0      0 59175060  39128 461128    0    0     0     0 12033  120  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 59174680  39128 461128    0    0     0     0 12058  134  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 59175052  39128 461128    0    0     0     0 12039  127  0  0 99  0  0
 1  0      0 59174812  39128 461128    0    0     0     0 12041  121  0  0 100  0  0

# dstat
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw
  0   2  98   0   0   0| 179k  369k|   0     0 |   0     0 |  12k  291
  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0     0 | 810B  880B|   0     0 |  12k  120
  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0    36k|1204B  400B|   0     0 |  12k  153
  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0     0 | 820B  400B|   0     0 |  12k  122
  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0     0 | 482B  400B|   0     0 |  12k  122
  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0     0 | 604B  400B|   0     0 |  12k  122
  0   0 100   0   0   0|   0     0 | 992B  400B|   0     0 |  12k  120
```

Comment: Did you install the Hyper-V Linux Integration Tools?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using the latest 3.4